# How do I regain entrance to the Soul Cairn?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

So I started the quest "Beyond Dead" and talked to Valrice, then I went to kill one of the guys but died. I got mad and left the Soul Cairn, but later I decided I wanted my wolf powers back, so I talked to Aela and got back my powers.

Now I want to go back in but it won't let me. What should I do? I'm working for the Dawnguard not Harkon.

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR:**

- As a part of the Dawnguard questline, you have an option to be soultrapped by Serana, allowing you to enter for the first time. *This is not available after you leave upon the quest completion*
- To enter again, you must become a Vampire Lord. You may need to "Rank up" to a level 2 Vampire Lord before being able to re-enter, but you should be able to re-enter at will.

From the [wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Soul_Cairn_(Dawnguard))

> One cannot enter the Soul Cairn **without being a vampire or being partially soul trapped**. Being soul trapped causes the Weakened Soul ability to activate, which decreases Magicka, health, and stamina while in the Soul Cairn. This can be negated after completing Chasing Echoes and talking to Valerica, who will instruct the Dragonborn to find the Soul Essence Gem. Upon doing so, all stats will return to normal.

Unfortunately I couldn't find any *clear* indications that you can become soul trapped again to re-enter. Becoming a vampire again *seemed* to be the only option, as Serana will no longer give you the option to become soul trapped again.

Comment: I did try to become a normal vampire, but it still wont let me in.

Comment: Should clarify that you need to become a Vampire Lord. I believe Serana has the option to do that

Comment: Yes that what I have heard, that Serana will turn you again. But she doesn't give me the option.

Comment: You may need to remove the werewolf curse for her to turn you, otherwise try entering the soul cairn, then walk outside and talk to Serana again

Comment: I tried all those things.

Comment: Are you sure that you need to be a Vampire Lord? [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Soul_Cairn) says that you just need to be a vampire.

Comment: @amaranth yes. The wiki is ambiguous, and testing it has shown the you need to be a *Vampire Lord*, not just a vampire

Answer (score 1):

Alright I figured it out, if you become a stage 2 vampire it will let you in.

Comment: This looks like an answer, but not a very well-written one. If you were to expand it a little (say, by describing how you figured that out, and what else you tried), you might get more upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is be a vampire lord before you enter her study again. I became one inside her study after becoming mortal again and it wouldn't let me in. All you have to do is walk to the balcony door, exit the study, and re-enter and you can now traverse the soul cairn.

Comment: This adds nothing new to the existing answers. When you reach 50 rep you can comment on other answers.

Answer (score -1):

I became mortal again and the soul carin glitched very badly where i had to exit out of the game. But to re-enter you must become a vampire lord again BEFORE entering her study or it wont let you.

Answer (score -1):

To enter you must be a vampire again. You have to be vampire lord level 2 and ask Serena about her studies. It will give you a clear shot of maybe getting Arvak the skeleton demon horse who has the same health as Shadowmere and does double damage. You will never lose him because he can be conjured anytime you need a companion demon purple fire skeleton horse.