# How do I regain entry to the soul cairn if neither me nor Serana is a vampire?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

So when I originally went into the soul cairn I had Serana turn me into a vampire, then I got cured. Later I got serana cured too. Now I have no idea how to return to the soul cairn.

Comment: [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Soul_Cairn) says that you need to be a vampire, but [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/174436) says that you need to be a Vampire Lord. Since you can’t become a Vampire Lord anymore now that Serana is cured, I suggest trying to get infected with normal vampirism from any NPC vampire. I think you will be able to re-enter the Soul Cairn after that, but I’m not sure.

Comment: You are a gift from Lucifer himself. What kind of sacrifice should I make as your reward?

Comment: I’m not sure what to make of that comment...

Comment: No human sacrifices. Sorry, but I'm not going to prison.

Comment: Okay, I was just being a nerd, I don't perform sacrifices nor worship Lucifer. I do however think he's waaay cooler than God.

Comment: He’s got nothing on Molag Bal.

Comment: From the [Elder Scrolls Wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Soul_Cairn_(Dawnguard)): “If access to the Soul Cairn is gained by becoming a Vampire Lord, and the condition is cured immediately after leaving, reentering will not be possible. Get Serana to turn the Dragonborn back into a Vampire Lord before returning to Valerica's Study for the first time (otherwise save outside the study, exit the game completely, start the game and load this save and have Serana turn you into a vampire lord and then renter the study) and it should be possible to enter the Cairn.”

Answer (score -1):

If you've been into the Soul Cairn via any method already you can access it as many times as you want without issue.

Comment: Not if you entered it by becoming a vampire, but you are no longer a vampire.

Comment: I've only ever entered the Soul Cairn being soul trapped, so I didn't think the developers would have an oversight as big as being locked out of re-entry, but this is Bethesda nothing's really concrete with them. The only option you have now is to travel to any location with vampires and let them smack you about until you contract Sanguinare Vampiris. Quite a pain,  soul trapping is the only worthwhile choice, it makes you weaker but doesn't force you into vampirism and gives infinite access without restriction.