# I can't go back to the Soul Cairn in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I tried going in as a vampire but it did not work. I had tried it with Serana as a follower and I tried it without her.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Does this answer your question? [How do I regain entrance to the Soul Cairn?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/174436/4797) If not, please [edit] your question, to provide more details and elaborate why.